# How to make an undo feature for a board game in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm finding it difficult implementing an undo feature for a game that I have developed using c# forms. I would like to have a button on the game screen which ,when clicked, reverses the move the player just made.

Anyone have an ideas how I would go about doing this ? I have been told that a stack is the best way to go about doing this but I'm unsure how to implement it.

Comment: How about Google `C#` and `stack` and get a reference like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=netframework-4.6.1). Use the generic one.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your game events into actions that can have methods `Do()` and `Undo()`.

Lets take Paint program as an example. User draws line on the given coordinates, you put `LineDrawnEvent` on the stack with all related data, and invoke `Do()` method, which actually draws a line on the canvas. When user clicks undo button, you pop item from your stack and invoke `Undo()` method, which in `LineDrawnEvent` should remove the line which user has drawn.

You can also have interface for that, something like `IProgramAction` with `Do()` and `Undo()` methods, so you can have different events, for example `CircleDrawnEvent` and `RectangularDrawnEvent` in the same stack.

And stack in your code will look something like

```
public Stack<IProgramAction> ProgramStack { get; set; }
```